# Is there a way to smooth out the transition of a graphics component from one point to another using Timer class in Java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am trying to get a simple animation done smoothly in Java using `Timer` class, i.e. *to move a `target` from its current position to the farthest end-of-frame horizontally*.

I have used the graphics component's current position inside the `Timer` class's `actionPerformed()` method and have been increasing the `x` location of the component by a certain amount but when I try to run it the component instantly jumps to the next location and waits for the timer to complete and repaint to a new location. *(I apologize if I am not phrasing the problem properly.)*

I have included the code as a whole so as to provide the entire context:

```java
public class FireAtBill extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4682094035006759518L;

    private int hits, misses;
    private Point targetPos;
    private Timer t;
    private BufferedImage crosshair, target;


    public FireAtBill() {

        Random random = new Random();
        targetPos = new Point(random.nextInt(500),random.nextInt(500) );
        t = new Timer(500, new TimerListener());
        t.start();

        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        try {
            crosshair = ImageIO.read(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/crosshair.jpg"));
            target = ImageIO.read(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/target.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawString("hits: " + hits + "  misses: " + misses, 0, 10);
        g2.drawImage(crosshair, 125, 50, this);
        g2.drawImage(target, targetPos.x, targetPos.y, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fire At Bill");
        frame.setSize(500,500 );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FireAtBill fireAtBill = new FireAtBill();
        frame.getContentPane().add(fireAtBill);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener{
        double x = targetPos.getX();
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (x <= 500||targetPos.getX() >= 0) {
                if (x<250) {
                    targetPos.setLocation(targetPos.getX()+15, targetPos.getY());
                }
                else {
                    targetPos.setLocation(targetPos.getX()-15, targetPos.getY());
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }

}
```

I expect the `target` to move smoothly across the screen horizontally, but the `target` is jumping from one location to another. 
I have tried to increment the `x` position of the `target` using smaller values and while this smooths out the movement, it does so at the cost of the speed of the `target` which I hope to implement as a variable which can be altered by changing its value.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found that by decreasing the delay value when initializing the `Timer` object I can speed up the repaint process here `t = new Timer(500, new TimerListener());` by changing `500` to something like `50`. **Decreasing this value will speed up the animation.**

And the smoothing can be implemented by decreasing the increment value inside the `actionPerformed()` method of the `TimeListener` class here `targetPos.setLocation(targetPos.getX()+15, targetPos.getY());`by changing the increment value `15` to something like `3`. **Decreasing this value will help smooth the animation.**

Comment: Decrease the time between updates to `5` milliseconds (I think that's about 200fps), then adjust the delta.  You might need to use a `double` value instead, but you'll get a much smoother and more control over the process

Comment: @MadProgrammer 200 fps sounds sweet... my system barely reaches 100. I'll go with 10 then. I agree with you on the delta, a `double` value would be smoother than the snail. Thanks.